# Unusual error when running create-react-app in terminal on Mac

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have never had an error before running create-react-app, but when I have run it on my Mac today I keep getting the below error and have not been able to resolve it. I've tried updating node, Yarn, eslint, CRA, and also clearing the node cache and nothing works. Why is this error occurring and how can I resolve it so I can install create-react-app?

```
Creating a new React app in /Users/...

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.10.1
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". Got "9.3.0"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd /Users/johnwolfe/printPackageTest/printtest has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting printtest/ from /Users/johnwolfe/printPackageTest
Done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error**

> error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
>   module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0". Got "9.3.0"
>   error Found incompatible module

**Question**

> Why is this error occurring and how can I resolve it so I can install
>   create-react-app?

**Answer**

You might consider updating your NodeJS version :) It's quite clear that it's an incompatible issue between your NodeJS and the create-react-app

Comment: thanks. dumb mistake on my part. i thought i had already upgraded it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, try to add "--use-npm" at the end of create react app commend.

```
create-react-app appname --use-npm
```

Happy hacking!